# DomPDF - php splitting every table row in new page

Tags: php, html, dompdf, invoice

I'm currently working on a project in which I've to create an invoice using domPDF. I found a template on github for nice invoice.
Now whenever I create a PDF it breaks every table row in new page and create a 5-6 pages PDF.

I've tried tweaking css of this template but no luck.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A simple, clean, and responsive HTML invoice template</title>

    <style>
    .invoice-box {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #555;
    }

    .invoice-box table {
        width: 100%;
        line-height: inherit;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .invoice-box table td {
        padding: 5px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
        font-size: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        color: #333;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
        background: #eee;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.details td {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.item td{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
        border-top: 2px solid #eee;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }

    /** RTL **/
    .rtl {
        direction: rtl;
        font-family: Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .rtl table {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .rtl table tr td:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="invoice-box">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="top">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title">
                                <img src="https://www.sparksuite.com/images/logo.png" style="width:100%; max-width:300px;">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Invoice #: 123<br>
                                Created: January 1, 2015<br>
                                Due: February 1, 2015
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="information">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Sparksuite, Inc.<br>
                                12345 Sunny Road<br>
                                Sunnyville, CA 12345
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Acme Corp.<br>
                                John Doe<br>
                                john@example.com
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="heading">
                <td>
                    Payment Method
                </td>

                <td>
                    Check #
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="details">
                <td>
                    Check
                </td>

                <td>
                    1000
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="heading">
                <td>
                    Item
                </td>

                <td>
                    Price
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item">
                <td>
                    Website design
                </td>

                <td>
                    $300.00
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item">
                <td>
                    Hosting (3 months)
                </td>

                <td>
                    $75.00
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item last">
                <td>
                    Domain name (1 year)
                </td>

                <td>
                    $10.00
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="total">
                <td></td>

                <td>
                   Total: $385.00
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want PDF output to be like this.
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific issue is, so no answer to the question, but the rendering is not so bad with the forthcoming 0.8.4 release. If you're willing to use an in-development version you should see better results, though for some reason the first page still shows as blank.

Comment: This issue only occur with tables, I just managed to convert this into div layout